# How to create various list from a grab data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to improve the code below. I want to add labels to a list from the same data text being grabbed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
r = requests.get('https://bscscan.com/tx/0x945d380c807137cd0b1299959bf364fc0ee2aec08fed361b71f2ead6dcfa3818', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})


soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
test = soup.select_one('div#rawtab textarea').text
print (test)
```

Current Output:

```
Function: lockTokens(address lpToken, uint256 amount, uint256 unlockTime, address withdrawer, uint8 feePaymentMode) ***


MethodID: 0x6167aa61

[0]:  0000000000000000000000009c95aa9407611b1fef6a2b16d7b0de3d03359136
[1]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000183e55dbab04396869
[2]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000625f7296
[3]:  000000000000000000000000c0ef93ad4c21053bf82d66f4e5513b0b542e329d
[4]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Needed Output:

```
Function: lockTokens(address lpToken, uint256 amount, uint256 unlockTime, address withdrawer, uint8 feePaymentMode) ***

address lpToken:       0000000000000000000000009c95aa9407611b1fef6a2b16d7b0de3d03359136
uint256 amount:        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000183e55dbab04396869
uint256 unlockTime:    00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000625f7296
address withdrawer:    000000000000000000000000c0ef93ad4c21053bf82d66f4e5513b0b542e329d
uint8 feePaymentMode:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Comment: It's just simple text substitution.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simple text search-and-replace.

```
text = """\
Function: lockTokens(address lpToken, uint256 amount, uint256 unlockTime, address withdrawer, uint8 feePaymentMode) ***


MethodID: 0x6167aa61

[0]:  0000000000000000000000009c95aa9407611b1fef6a2b16d7b0de3d03359136
[1]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000183e55dbab04396869
[2]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000625f7296
[3]:  000000000000000000000000c0ef93ad4c21053bf82d66f4e5513b0b542e329d
[4]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"""

params = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('Function'):
        print(line)
        i = line.find('(')
        j = line.find(')')
        params = line[i+1:j].split(', ')
        print()
    elif line.startswith('['):
        print( f"{params[int(line[1])]:20} {line[3:]}" )
```

Output:

```
Function: lockTokens(address lpToken, uint256 amount, uint256 unlockTime, address withdrawer, uint8 feePaymentMode) ***

address lpToken      :  0000000000000000000000009c95aa9407611b1fef6a2b16d7b0de3d03359136
uint256 amount       :  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000183e55dbab04396869
uint256 unlockTime   :  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000625f7296
address withdrawer   :  000000000000000000000000c0ef93ad4c21053bf82d66f4e5513b0b542e329d
uint8 feePaymentMode :  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```